# Can I shield mySQL databases on a server from problems with one database

Tags: mysql

I have a server with multiple MySQL databases.
Periodically, I have a problem with one database that may be because of programming errors or data errors.  Maybe there's a runaway query. Problems happen...  But that problem with the one database can slow down or lock up all the databases on the server, making a smaller problem a huge problem.

Is there anything I can do to contain the effects within one database and let the other databases run smoothly.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the types of problems you're encountering? Are you running into deadlocks? Or the mysql daemon won't start? Or you're running out of connections?

Comment: we have run out of connections. We have had never ending Select statements. we fix the errors as they are discovered. My question is more structural. Since problems will always happen, I would like to find a way to contain problems within the one database and not affect other applications running on the server. Maybe that's the difference between MySQl and enterprise databases like Oracle or SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious solution would be to run multiple MySQL instances.  Although there may be less drastic measures you can take, depending on the exact nature of the specific error conditions you're trying to avoid.

You might have a look at [Setting Account Resource Limits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html). Setting the max per-user connections may go a long way to help some of the problems it sounds like you're facing.

Certainly other database systems can provide additional safety against these types of things, but that doesn't mean MySQL can't be configured for your needs.  PostgreSQL, for instance, provides a "statement timeout" variable, which we use at my work, to set a global upper-bound for query run-time, just as a safe-guard against long-running queries. (It can be easily overridden on a per-connection basis if we expect a specific query to take longer than your default of 300 seconds)  I don't find a similar option for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

To fully contain problems from runaway/recursive queries, you need to move that database onto it's own server. The query could potentially use up all allocated memory/disk space that your other databases need.

Comment: The point here, is that you don't know when a problem will occur and on which of the 25 databases it will occur.

Comment: Oh, I see. I assumed that only one of your databases had the 'runaway' queries which you could then isolate. I still stand by my comment about needing to isolate RAM issues though. Multiple instances of mysql on the same server still share the same RAM. If your problems are severe enough that the 'runaway' queries do affect other databases, i would suggest running multiple instances in separate VMs, that way you can allocate hardware to each individually.